# Can't open a port 587 on windows 2008 server

Tags: windows, server, port, windows-server-2008

I have virtual server with Win 2008 R2 SP1 Web Edition and Plesk 12.018 and i can't for the love of God open port 587 on it. Whatever i do it remains closed.

I have disabled every firewall i have found on server and still blocked. I have added inbound and outbound rules for that port in windows firewall, still blocked. I honestly have no idea where to look any more.

Any pointers to right direction would be most welcomed. Is there something on IIS maybe? Or some other server component im not familiar with? How to open that port?

Ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have MailEnable mail server, check Mailenable SMTP settings:

SMTP -> Properties -> "Inbound" tab -> "Port Settings" Settings 
Set:
SMTP port = 25
**Submission port = 587**

Comment: No that was not it. You see Mail is working fine if i use webmail or smtp port 25. But our teleoperater blocks usage of port 25 and i cant open 587 on server. Somewhere something is blocking that port and it is not plesk or windows firewalll.

Comment: I apologize for previus comment cause the problem was indeed with Mailenable. If anyone else is having same problem you have to configure MailEnable from scratch.